# Detect which part of an imageView was touch?

Tags: android, touch, imageview

Is it possible to detect on android what part of an image (right, left) was touched?

Comment: yea, get the touch event coordinates and check if the x value is greater or lesser than image.width/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, attaching a touch listener will allow you to handle the MotionEvent, which contains the actual touch position; just do something like i`f(event.getX() < image.width / 2) { // touch on left } else { // touch on right; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you use TouchEvent you can get the x and y of the touch.

Answer (score 0):

Or you put 2 buttons behind your ImageView, then you have the click handler included directly